# I want to store encrypted credentials and use them to open a powershell instance and run a script that makes a change to a field in AD

Tags: powershell, scripting, securestring

Below is my code, I've used the same process for connecting to sftp securely. I'm getting the error at the bottom of my post. Not sure if I'm missing a step in the creation of the key and password. Thanks.

```
#Set the credentials
$Password = Get-Content "c:\password.txt" | 
ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content "c:\aes.key")
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('serviceaccount', $Password)

# Start a new instance of Windows PowerShell using the credentials 
# stored in $Credential and run the script in $scriptblock
$powershellPath = "$env:windir\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$process = Start-Process $powershellPath -Credential $Credential -NoNewWindow `
-ArgumentList ("-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noninteractive -noprofile " + $scriptBlock) -PassThru
```

```
# Script to execute in the new PowerShell instance
$scriptBlock = {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    Get-ADUser ecarlsson | Set-ADUser -Manager bbob

    Read-Host    
}
```

I tried the code above and go the password error below.

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The user name or password is incorrect.
At\filepath \\fV3.ps1:7 char:12
+ $process = Start-Process $powershellPath -Credential $Credential -NoN ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: You need to define the script block before using it, but that is a later issue.

Comment: There are easier ways to run a scriptblock using other credentials from within PowerShell then using `Start-Process`. Have a look at `help Invoke-Command -Online` or `help Start-Job -Online`.

Comment: You are sure that the password file only contains one line of text?

Comment: You can try troubleshoot the SecureString by **temporarily** storing the password as plain text in your file. `$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString (Get-Content 'c:\password.txt') -AsPlainText -Force`

Comment: PowerShell and credentials doesn't support double hop authentication out of the box. Are you running the script directly on a DC?

Comment: I'm running it on a jump host that has connectivity to a DC. I'm trying to set up an automation software to run this. So just to clarify powershell will not pass on the credentials to the scriptblock where I'm actually connecting to AD? Thank you.

Comment: No, not OoB. You can set up support for double hop in several ways. The easiest way is to use PWSH 7.x using ssh as the transport protocol instead of default WinRM. The second best is to create a stored remote session before hand, that can be reused (reusing it will enable double hop). The other options keeps getting more complex (Kerberos delegation, JEA and ~~CredSSP~~). Se [MS Learn - Making the second hop in PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ps-remoting-second-hop)